# python: calculation of time progress

Tags: python, time, date-arithmetic

I am writing python code that handles a text file and, for each line of input, calculates the time involved with the action described in that line, then reports a "running time". Required output like

```
        lapse     time
start            12:00
action1  0:37    12:37
action2  1:01    13:38
action3  0:30    14:08
```

I came to some possible approaches but all looked awkward. Most of all I am confused about using either "time" or "strftime" or "datetime" or perhaps even something else. I am sure a simple elegant solution must exist.

NB timezones and DST are of no concern, if I can get to show UTC that is sufficient, at least for a beginning. In a later stage the last column (UTC) might be augmented by a column "local time" but that is secondary.

Edited, for apparent lack of clarity, to add example pseudo-code:

```
 TIME='12:00'
 PCS_PER_HOUR=750
 with infile:
  read line of data
  process data, including calc of PCS_DONE
  LAPSE=PCS_DONE/PCS_PER_HOUR
  TIME += LAPSE
  print(' .....   ' ,format(data, data, data, LAPSE, TIME))
```

My question is how to make the "TIME='12:00" into something that python can easily handle, and increment with a calculated integer number of seconds or minutes or whatever.

Comment: Please share your "some possible approaches."

Comment: They were along the lines of keeping separate variables for number of hours, number of minutes, then adding "the artisanal way" like "if minutes > 60 : hours +=1, minutes -= 60 " . Essentially not using any time-specific functions at all, while python has a wealth of them, in fact so much as to cause confusion.

Comment: Keep the time in seconds, as returned by `time.time()`. Print it any way you like using `strftime()`.

Comment: Will look into that. time.time() might not even be needed but "keep the time in seconds" might well be the keyword I was missing.

Comment: @Karel everyone is pointing you towards using [`time.struct_time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.struct_time) because that's the Python Standard Library's method of "keeping separate variables". Effectively you have one variable (the `struct_time`), and each of the members of the tuple are hours, minutes, seconds, etc. Most of the many "time specific functions" you're confused over are in fact wrappers to C's `time.h` library.

Comment: It would also help if you provided an idea of how your input file represents `action1`, `action2`, `action3`. I presume that would consist of three lines of the text file?

Comment: Yes. I really thought my description to be clear: "for each line of input, calculates the time involved" &c. So if my example shows three lines each with an elapsed time it must mean there have been three lines of input.

Comment: @Matthew: ok, yes, time.struct_time then, I'm ok with that. How do I assign the '12:00' from my example into that? I can of course dissect it into 12 hours, 0 minutes, 0 seconds, but what comes next? Again, dates and time zones and daylight saving are not relevant and indeed disregarded on purpose. I only want a running counter of time elapsed since a given start time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `datetime.timedelta`.

Set the start time.

```
In [1]: import datetime
```

The initial time is 12 hours.

```
In [2]: start = datetime.timedelta(hours=12)

In [3]: start
Out[3]: datetime.timedelta(0, 43200)
```

Let's say that `LAPSE` is 0.23 hours (pieces divided by pieces per hour yields hours).

```
In [4]: action1 = datetime.timedelta(hours=0.23)
```

Now you can format the times like you want. The standard representation is hours, minutes and seconds:

```
In [5]: str(start)
Out[5]: '12:00:00'

In [6]: str(start+action1)
Out[6]: '12:13:48'
```

Comment: Thanks, but not really an answer. I calculate the time lapse like LAPSE=PCS_DONE/PCS_PER_HOUR or so. How can I get such a result into the strftime, which seems to expect a tuple as its input? In other words, the "current time" is not involved at all.

Comment: Then only use the deltas.

Comment: Again thanks, but you seem to miss my issue. I edited the opening question, adding a bit of pseudo code.

Comment: I've completely changed the answer based on your edit.

Comment: And now the question is answered. Thanks indeed!